# Vite Proxy Not Forwarding Requests to Backend Server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, proxy, vite

I'm developing a React web application with a frontend served by Vite and a backend server running on a different port. (NodeJS)  I've set up a proxy in my vite.config.js to forward requests from the frontend to the backend, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'client/dist',
    publicDir: 'public',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'client/app.jsx',
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 5173,
    proxy: {
      '/v1': 'http://localhost:8080'
    },
  },
});
```

When I make a fetch request to /v1/restaurants/7 from my frontend code, I expect the request to be forwarded to http://localhost:8080/v1/restaurants/7. However, I'm getting the HTML of my homepage as a response, and there's no log of the request in my backend server logs.

If I make the same request directly to the backend server (bypassing the Vite server), it works correctly. I've also tried enabling CORS on my backend server, and that allows the fetch request to work when I use an absolute URL.

I've cleared my browser cache, restarted the Vite server, and checked the network tab in developer tools, but the issue persists. I'm not seeing any errors in the console.

I can replicate the issue with postman:
if I call http://localhost:8080/v1/restaurants/7 the response is fine
If I call http://localhost:5173/v1/restaurants/7 (same structure but using the vite port)  I get the same wrong response (My html index page)